# Why does the integral symbol disappear when applying a functional derivative?

Tags: general-relativity, differentiation, integration, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

it is known that variation is defined by following:

[image]

but could anyone tell me why the integral symbol disappears after following functional derivative?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define functional
$$ G[g]~:=~\int \!d^4x ~\sqrt{-g(x)}.\tag{0}$$
Method 1:
$$\begin{align} \int \!d^4x ~\color{red}{\frac{\delta G[g]}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}(x)}} \delta g_{\mu\nu}(x)
~=~&\delta G[g]\cr
~\stackrel{(0)}{=}~& \int \!d^4x ~\color{red}{\frac{\partial\sqrt{-g(x)}}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}(x)}} \delta g_{\mu\nu}(x).\end{align} \tag{1}$$
Method 2:
$$\begin{align} \color{red}{\frac{\delta G[g]}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}(y)}}  
~\stackrel{(0)}{=}~& \int \!d^4x ~\frac{\delta\sqrt{-g(x)}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}(y)}\cr
~=~& \int \!d^4x ~\frac{\partial\sqrt{-g(x)}}{\partial g_{\kappa\lambda}(x)}\frac{\delta g_{\kappa\lambda}(x)}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}(y)} \cr
~=~& \int \!d^4x ~\frac{\partial\sqrt{-g(x)}}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}(x)}\delta^4(x\!-\!y) \cr
~=~&\color{red}{\frac{\partial\sqrt{-g(y)}}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}(y)}}.\end{align}\tag{2}$$